# Are BDSM sexual practices correlated with or related to social-dominance orientation?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, abnormal-psychology, statistics, personality-disorder

When I think about [BDSM sexual practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BDSM) and [sexual sadism disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_sadism_disorder), I tend to think that it sounds like something that some people with a social dominance orientation would be interested in. This [Wiki page on a subtype of BDSM sexual practice called master/slave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(BDSM)) reminds me of how feudal lords owned slaves and serfs.

I feel that the economic relationship between a slave and a slave owner looks psychologically similar to the master/slave role play. And I also think that what's referred to as the sexual sadism disorder is an exaggerated version of the regular BDSM sexual desire.

Are there any scientific studies that tested the correlational relationship between BDSM sexual practices and the sexual sadism disorder with the social dominance orientation trait? Does having the SDO trait increase your chances of seeking out BDSM sexual practices or being diagnosed with a sexual sadism disorder?